# What type of relay should I be using?

Tags: arduino, relay

So I'm currently looking to control a lightbulb for some inefficient lighting to produce heat for a mini-greenhouse I am building. I'm looking at plugging in a wall wart 12V DC adapter and wire that to the bulb. In terms of relays/solid state relays what should I look into buying? 12V - 5V DC relay?

Answer (score 2):

The relay selection isn't really mission critical. You rarely if ever directly drive them from a microcontroller, like your Arduino's. Most of the time, a simple npn transistor is used, unless you have a n-channel mosfet you want to use (and it has the right VGS value).

The choice of relay for these one off projects is basically cost, and what voltage you have available. Here, you have 12 Volts from the light supply, and 5 Volts from the regulated Arduino rail. Most likely, your powering the Arduino from the 12v supply. Since isolation likely isn't needed here (standalone project, no mains switching, no computer connection), then a 12v relay is fine. It would avoid taxing the limited regulator on the Arduino, and can easily be driven by a transistor on the Arduino output.

The transistor would be determined by the current needed to drive the relay, but pretty much any relay with a coil current of under 1 Amp can be driven by a standard 2N2222. Heck, a typical small relay only needs under 200 mA coil current, so a smaller 2N3904 works too.

The relay choice does depend on the light current you expect to drive, and how often you intend to switch it on or off. If your not thinking PWM to reduce the lighting, and are planning minutes or hours on, minutes or hours off, then any common relay would work. Once your switching it off and on in seconds or fractions of a second, then a mechanical relay is no longer an option.

Answer (score 1):

So?

> 12V - 5V DC relay?

You buy a relay with a coil voltage to suit your controller and a contact rating to suit the current of your lamp which you haven't specified.

> ... a lightbulb for some efficient lighting to produce heat for a mini-greenhouse ...

Efficient lighting means "converts a high proportion of the input energy into light". If you want heat you are looking for inefficient lighting to convert input energy into heat. Don't make the mistake of thinking you can get more energy out of a lamp in the form of light and heat than you put in (in the form of electrical energy) just by buying something labeled as "efficient".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm looking to control the bulb with low voltage and not AC mains for safety purposes.

Comment: Also, my fault: Definitely meant inefficient lighting, it's been a long night and haven't been getting much sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use a common transistor switching circuit as thousands of people have used with their Arduinos, et.al.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhZuoU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you are using a 12V DC relay when what you really want is a 120VAC timer , with a relay built in, which will then power the AC light bulbs.  It's off the shelf stuff at Wal-Mart.  (I've already done that)

Comment: I'm looking for low voltage due to safety reasons. I don't want to be connecting 120VAC

Comment: @rmdlp you would connect a 12V dc adapter to the timer, and your lights to that. It's a regular consumer product, not a electronic parts component. Tim is suggesting you avoid the project all together.

Comment: @rmdlp that said, you won't get much heat from a 12v light.

Comment: exactly, (Passerby), unless he wants to do the project for educational rather than practical reasons.  It takes a lot of light to grow stuff.